# iPhone - UIScrollView inside UIView not scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` which contains lot of labels, buttons, textviews. But there is a certain part of that `UIView` that I want to make scrollable.Here is how the structure of my nib is.

```
-UIVIew
-UIImageView - backgroundImage
-UILabels
-UIButtons
-UIScrollView
-UITextViews
```

Are touch events getting assigned to somewhere else? Here is a code of my scrollview which I have written in `viewDidLoad`. I only want the textview inside `UIScrollview` to be scrollable

```
scrollView.delegate = self;    
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
[scrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[scrollView addSubview:textview];
```

Am I mising something? is my approach right?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I dont understand why u need a scrollview inside a textview? what is ur purpose?

Comment: Your nib file structure hierarchy is confusing? can u please share snapshot of that view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scroll.contentSize= CGSizeMake(320,2700);`// You can use contentsize according to your requirements

You have put here only scrollview code. So,I can't figure out what is wrong. Use following reference...

[UIScrollView With UITextField](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/scrollview-example-in-iphone/)

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, I'm trying it out.. And I dont want scrollview inside textview but textview inside textview. The problem is, scrollview comes inside main UIView and there are other subviews as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Nit and adali. I was missing [scrollview setcontentsize] in my code. Thank a lot for the help, I was really struggling with this.. Pity I cant accept both of your answers.. ;)

Comment: Even, I dont understand why u need a textview inside a scrollview ? what is ur purpose..I just typed scrollview and textview in miss position..Anyway happy that you got solution..

Comment: Yes I know textview can be scrollable, but I might add label or image in that portion, so I wanted all of the views scrolling together.

Comment: I'm new to iOS, I do a lot of Java (Mainly for Android) and even (C# for Windows Phone Apps), Why I always see magical constant values for height, is there no way for auto expand to content size and scroll accordingly!!!! is iOS/AutoLayout that bad or it's just because of my limited knowledge cause I'm new to it!!

Comment: I'm new to iOS, I do a lot of Java (Mainly for Android) and even (C# for Windows Phone Apps), Why I always see "magical" constant values that doesn't make sense for height, is there no way for auto expand to content size and scroll accordingly!!!! is iOS/AutoLayout that bad or it's just because of my limited knowledge cause I'm new to it!!

Answer (score 5):

```
[scrollView setContentSize:theSizeYouWantToScroll]
```

Comment: Sorry, the formatting of the hierarchy is not clear in my question. So here is how it is structured. My nib has few buttons, some imageViews,few labels and at the bottom, I have a scrollview, and inside it, I have a textview. Now the text inside scrollview is dynamic and I only want that part at the bottom to be scrollable.

Comment: you can not scroll only part of scrollview, or you want to make the textView scrool inside?

Answer (score 1):

You better should let the compiler figure out the height, instead of setting it yourself.

```
CGFloat height = 0;
for (UIView *v in _scrollView.subviews) {
    height += v.frame.size.height;
}

_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, height);
```