# UIScrollView inside a custom UIView not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've created a custom `UIView` which contains a `UIScrollView`.  I then fill it with a `UIView` which is 3 times as wide.

Inside my `UIViewController`, I instantiate my custom `UIView` and add it to the view.

However, when I attempt to scroll the scrollview horizontally, it doesn't move.

I'm setting the contentView and the contentSize.  User interaction is enabled.  When I touch the buttons, they respond.  But the view doesn't scroll.

Is there something special you need to do when adding a custom `UIView` with a scrollview onto a `UIViewController` (like passing down the touches, or something like that?).

Comment: Did you set the contentSize property of UIScrollView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - UIScrollView inside UIView not scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278112/iphone-uiscrollview-inside-uiview-not-scrolling)

Comment: @KudoCC - yes, contentSize property is being set.  In fact no matter what I set it to, the scrollview does not scroll.

Comment: Can you post some code on how you add subView of UIScrollView and how to config the UIScrollView. Upload your demo is even better.

Comment: Guys.  I solved the problem.  When I added a UIPageControl to my view, it added it INSIDE the scrollview control in the IB.  That blocked it from scrolling.  By moving the PageControl out of the scrollview in the IB (i.e no longer as a subview) it works fine.  Thanks for all your help! @KudoCC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I added a UIPageControl to my UIView in the IB, it inserted the UIPageControl as a subview of the UIScrollView.  It was thing which stopped my scrollview from scrolling.

By removing the UIPageControl from the scrollview, it all worked fine.

BAD!
[image: Bad]

GOOD!
[image: Good]